# Remove custom UINavigationBar for MFMailComposer and MFMessageComposer

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationbar

I've added custom navigationbars(images) to my app with [UINavigationbar appearance] and the old drawRect method (for iOS4) as well.

The problem is when I try to start a MFMailComposer or a MFMessageComposer, it uses the same custom navigationbar(the image I put in) but I can't change their titles (it is not allowed anyway).

How could I "disable" the custom navigation bar for these controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 5.0+, you can nil-out the background image when you present the  `mailComposeViewController`, using

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Of course, be sure to restore your custom background image when you dismiss the mail composer.